# Hypoglycemic persons gym plan?

Tags: weightlifting, crossfit

Hypoglycemia, also known as **low blood sugar**, is when blood sugar decreases to below normal levels. This may result in a variety of symptoms including clumsiness, trouble talking, confusion, loss of consciousness, seizures, or death. A feeling of hunger, sweating, shakiness, and weakness may also be present.

So what should be Hypoglycemic person gym plan?

Should a Hypoglycemic person focus on cardio, weightlifting or CrossFit?

Comment: Given the condition, a hypoglycemic person should consult a physician.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your doctor, but if the doctor does not know about nutrition, he might just continue to give you medications and that is it.

You can also check with various doctors the information that are used by other people with the same issue reported by doctors like in this link:

https://youtu.be/icrqXwlp4ys

https://youtu.be/LvaVsnHbIbI

There are tons of medical papers released on this available on the net.

Also remember that you are less likely to need glucose with aerobic training that with anaerobic training.

Comment: Dr.Berg is great. Learning a lot from him. He does lift dead weights. Wanted to make sure about the issue. Want a short but effective workout.